# How do I pass a high-resolution photo to instagram on iOS?

Tags: ios, instagram

I've successfully be able to use the Instagram iPhone hooks to open Instagram and present it with a photo successfully from my application. But the image (already in high res) is automatically cropped to 612x612 px.
How can I make Instagram keep the original resolution?

Original source: [UIDocumentInteractionController annotation property doesn't copy caption to presented appliction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013066/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-annotation-property-doesnt-copy-caption-to-pres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (612x612) is the fixed resolution which can be used for images to be shared on Instagram. So if your image is not looking perfect after being shared to Instagram, then you should go for optimizing the resolution in app same as that to be used in Instagram.

Comment: You mean I should scale my image to that res before passing to instagram?

Comment: Yes exactly because the images not havking resolution as 612x612 would not be excepted in Instagram.